# Elm text overflowing specified dimensions: overflow hidden or scroll

Tags: elm

I find I need an element to contain some amount of text which is not of a fixed size (a log of actions taken), where that element is of a fixed size. Doing the obvious thing gets undesirable results:

http://ikeran.org/images/overflow2.png

The code I'm using:

```
renderLog w h log =
  let rh = truncate ((toFloat h) * 0.2)
      contents = map (\m -> Text.text <| Text.height 12 <| Text.toText m) log
      d = flow down contents in
  size w rh d
```

I'd expect the "size" call to cut off the contents at that size. It doesn't. This is unsurprising when you're sufficiently familiar with HTML -- the default `overflow` is `visible`.

If I were using CSS, I could simply set `overflow` to `hidden` or `scroll` and go on my merry way. Is there a recommended way of accomplishing this with Elm?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is pretty low-level. What you can do is fit those lines of text into the log until you run out of the space you meant to use. [I got this idea from the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elm-discuss/jWACir58Wig/discussion).

```
renderLog w h log =
  let contents = map (\m -> width w <| Text.text <| Text.height 12 <| Text.toText m) log
      heights = filter (\n -> n <= h) <| scanl1 (+) <| map heightOf contents
      d = flow down <| take (length heights) contents
  in height h d
```

What you do is force every piece of text to already be the right width. That ensures that when you then measure the height, that will be the height it has in the log.
Then you measure each of the heights and find when the sum of the heights becomes larger than the given parameter `h`. Taking only the text items up to when happens will ensure that your log doesn't overflow.

Here's a running example: http://share-elm.com/sprout/52da7873e4b06194fd2d4149